# Discrepency in FFT linear algebra in MATLAB vs Python

Tags: python, matlab, fft

Stack Overflow does not support LaTex formatting so I will refer to the complex conjugate as `*`, and the hermitian conjugate as `'`.

I have four operators for the forwards and backwards FFT and iFFT (for 3D vectors stored as 1D in Fortran formatting, where 'S is the shape of my 3D array):

```
def cI(in_vec):
    fft_vec = in_vec.reshape(S, order='F')
    fft_vec = np.fft.fftn(fft_vec, S)
    return fft_vec.reshape(-1, order='F')

def cJ(in_vec):
    ifft_vec = in_vec.reshape(S, order='F')
    ifft_vec = np.ifft.fftn(fft_vec, S)
    return fft_vec.reshape(-1, order='F')

def cIdag(in_vec):
    return np.prod(S) * cJ(in_vec)

def cJdag(in_vec):
    return 1. / np.prod(S) * cI(in_vec)
```

To verify my operators, I want to check to make sure that:

`(a'Jb)* == b'I'a` and `(a'Jb)* == b'J'a`, for all vectors a and b.

I am working on a problem set that was originally written in MATLAB and am doing it in Python. It is true in MATLAB that:

```
conj(a'*cI(b)) == b'*cIdag(a)
```

and

```
conj(a'*cJ(b)) == b'cJdag(a)
```

Which I am getting to work out in my Python version when `a` and `b` are real vectors. However, this check fails when they are complex. My check:

```
a=np.random.rand(np.prod(S),1)+1j*np.random.rand(np.prod(S),1)
b=np.random.rand(np.prod(S),1)+1j*np.random.rand(np.prod(S),1)
res1 = np.conj(np.dot(np.conj(a).T, cI(b)))
res2 = np.dot(np.conj(b).T, cIdag(a))
```

And `res1 != res2`.

Comment: Just to make sure: You are not confusing Matlab's transpose (.') and complex-conjugate transpose ('), are you? I'm asking because it happens a lot...

Comment: How big are the differences?  What do you get with `(res1 - res2).abs().max()`?  If it is very small, then it is just normal floating point issues.  MATLAB and Python has some negligible numerical differences in their dot product.

Comment: I do indeed want the hermitian conjugate (aka complex-conjugate transpose) also the differences are much greater than floating point error, so that is not it. I did not actually put the res1 != res2 statement, I printed out the two values, I can see why that would be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue, my operators were Hermitian it was my test that was wrong. I should have done:

```
a=np.random.rand(np.prod(S))+1j*np.random.rand(np.prod(S))
b=np.random.rand(np.prod(S))+1j*np.random.rand(np.prod(S))
```

instead of

```
a=np.random.rand(np.prod(S),1)+1j*np.random.rand(np.prod(S),1)
b=np.random.rand(np.prod(S),1)+1j*np.random.rand(np.prod(S),1)
```